# Theming class extends View (Button) with AppCompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-button, android-theme, android-styles

I have declared `Button` inside my XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/custom_id"
    android:theme="@style/BlueButtonTheme"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/custom_string"/>
```

most important line is styling with `BlueButtonTheme`:

```
<style name="BlueButtonTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/BlueButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/BlueButtonStyle</item>

    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue_dark</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/blue_dark</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/blue_dark</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/blue</item>

    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/blue_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/blue_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/blue_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/blue</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="BlueButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue_dark</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/blue_dark</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/blue_dark</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/blue</item>

    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/blue_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/blue_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/blue_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/blue</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

And `Button` is blue in all os versions, nice... Now I want to create custom `MyButton extends Button`, but when I set in XML:

```
<com.package.name.MyButton
    android:id="@+id/custom_id"
    android:theme="@style/BlueButtonTheme"
    ...
```

widget will stay gray in e.g. Android 4.1 (physical test device), but have white text and a bit blue when pressed/selected. 5.0 and above works. My button don't have any additional logic (for now), only set of constructors. How to apply working theme for this custom widget extending `Button`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

few hours of tries and 10 minutes after posting above question I've found proper answer: `extends AppCompatButton` (from support v7), not `android.widget.Button`